# Wraping text within a table's td

Tags: html, sql

I am working on trying to clean up a customers evaluation software. In this example, the text doesn't wrap within the box. Adding a fixed size to the table doesn't help, as the information called from the SQL database just places it on top with no warping.

```
    <tr>
        <td valign="bottom" align="center"><br />
            <table style="background-color: #EFEFEF; box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #999; table-layout:fixed; width:400px" border=1 rules=none frame=box cellpadding="5">
                ![enter image description here][1]<tr><td width=250px height="90px" valign="top"><pre>' . base64_decode($eval['note']) . '</pre></td></tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
```

What steps should I look at doing or code should I add to fix this formatting error? Attached is a screen shot of the UI.

Thank you,

Paul

Answer (score 0):

You are inserting your data inside a <pre> block, effectively telling the browser not to wrap the text. I assume you do this so that literal newlines in the 'note' data are indeed printed.

To alter wrapping space-characters and newline functionality of an element, you can use the CSS white-space property. So, to get what you want (both wrapping AND literal newlines), you can set white-space to either pre-line or pre-wrap, depending on your need. Eg. change the <pre> to

```
...<pre style="white-space:pre-wrap;">' . base64_decode($eval['note']) . '</pre>...
```

See [the reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space) for more details

Good luck,

bob

Comment: Thank you for your input. I attempted your method, while it didn't break anything it also didn't do anything. You are right to assume the previous guy put the <pre> in there to preserve the data, but even if I remove it, the get the same result. What do you recommend when not using pre?